# Simplify $\overline{i\left(\overline{\left(1+i\right)\left(\overline{13+2i}\right)}\right)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I tried to just do this problem from inside out, but I'm not getting it right. Why isn't the answer $\sqrt{346}$?

What I did: The first magnitude gives $\sqrt{13^2+2^2}=\sqrt{173}$. Then, multiply that to $1+i$ to get $\sqrt{173}+\sqrt{173}i$ The magnitude of that is $\sqrt{346}$. That multiplied by $i$ gives $\sqrt{346}i$ which has magnitude of just $\sqrt{346}$.

Comment: Show all your steps and we'll point out your mistake.

Comment: What is the answer you are supposed to get? Those look like complex conjugates, not magnitudes.

Comment: oh shoot RIP thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is that you think $\overline{blah}$ means the *magnitude* of $blah$. In fact it is the usual notation for the *complex conjugate* of $blah$:
$$ \overline{a+bi}=a-bi $$
when $a,b$ are real.

Comment: $\overline{a+i b}=a-i b$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Besides the issue of the meaning, outside in happens to work out better because of the following identities:

- $\overline{wz} = \overline w \, \overline z$
- $\overline{(\overline z)} = z$